# Why recursion in java is so slow compared to .net?

Tags: c#, java

I wrote an algorithm to find all the paths possible between two points. i wrote the algorithm in both c#.net and java. The algorithm produces around 40,000 possible paths. To my amazement the algorithm in C#.net took only 13 mins to complete (in i3 processor), while java could not complete even in 4 hrs.

recursion may be slow in java , but i don't think this much.

Is there anything i am missing ?

Ok here is the requirement , a maze is a two dimensional array which contains numbers 0,1,2 and 3. 0 represents the walkable points, 1 represents the obstacle , 2 the starting point and 3 the exit point. the program was to find all the paths from point 2 to 3 by touching all 0s only one time. we cannot step over 1s as they are obstacles.

### here is the code in C#.Net

```
public class Maze
{
    //Represents each point in the Maze.
    private class Node
    {
        private int val;

        public Node(int num)
        {
            val = num;

            switch (num)
            {
                case 1: IsPit = true;
                    break;
                case 2: IsEntranceNode = true;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    IsExitNode = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsPit { get; private set; }
        public bool IsVisited { get; set; }
        public bool IsExitNode { get; private set; }
        public bool IsEntranceNode { get; private set; }

        public Node UpNode { get; set; }
        public Node DownNode { get; set; }
        public Node LeftNode { get; set; }
        public Node RightNode { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion

    //Number of pits in the maze.
    private int numberOfPits;

    //Stack traces the path traversed.
    private Stack<String> pathTraversed;

    //Represents the maze.All Nodes are wired to its adjacent nodes.
    private Node[,] Maze { get; set; }

    //Number of paths found.
    private int pathCount = 1;

    //displays a set.
    static void printSet(int[,] set)
    {
        Console.Write(" \t");
        for (var i = 0; i < set.GetLength(1); i++)
            Console.Write(i + "  ");

        Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------");

        for (var i = 0; i < set.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Console.Write((char)(65 + i) + " | \t");
            for (var j = 0; j < set.GetLength(1); j++)
                Console.Write(set[i, j] + "  ");

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] set2 = new int[7, 7] {   { 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1 } 
                                    };          

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nSet 2");
        Console.WriteLine("=====");
        printSet(set2);

        Console.WriteLine("\nPath found");
        Console.WriteLine("==========");
        startTime = DateTime.Now;
        new Maze().AddPoints(set2).FindPaths();
        endTime = DateTime.Now;
        difference = endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalMinutes;
        Console.WriteLine("Time taken in mins : " + difference);
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    //Adds points to the maze.Transforms a matrix to 2 dimensional connected nodes.
    public Program AddPoints(int[,] matrix)
    {
        Maze = new Node[matrix.GetLength(0), matrix.GetLength(1)];

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Node node = Maze[i, j];

                if (node == null)
                {
                    node = new Node(matrix[i, j]);
                    Maze[i, j] = node;
                }
                if (!(i - 1 < 0))
                    Maze[i - 1, j].DownNode = node;

                if (!(i + 1 > matrix.GetLength(0) - 1))
                {
                    var downNode = Maze[i + 1, j];
                    if (downNode == null)
                        Maze[i + 1, j] = new Node(matrix[i + 1, j]);
                    Maze[i + 1, j].UpNode = node;
                }

                if (!(j - 1 < 0))
                    Maze[i, j - 1].RightNode = node;

                if (!(j + 1 > matrix.GetLength(1) - 1))
                {
                    var leftNode = Maze[i, j + 1];
                    if (leftNode == null)
                        Maze[i, j + 1] = new Node(matrix[i, j + 1]);
                    Maze[i, j + 1].LeftNode = node;
                }

                node.Name = ((char)(65 + i)).ToString() + j.ToString();
                if (node.IsPit)
                    numberOfPits++;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    //Finds path between the start node and end node.
    public void FindPaths()
    {
        var startNode = Maze[0, 0];

        if (!startNode.IsEntranceNode)
            throw new Exception("Node is not starting node.");

        pathTraversed = new Stack<string>();

        pathTraversed.Push(startNode.Name);
        Traverse(startNode.RightNode);
        Traverse(startNode.DownNode);
        Traverse(startNode.LeftNode);
        Traverse(startNode.UpNode);
    }

    //Traverses a node.
    private void Traverse(Node node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return;

        if (node.IsEntranceNode || node.IsPit || node.IsVisited)
            return;

        if (node.IsExitNode)
        {
            pathTraversed.Push(node.Name);
            if (pathTraversed.Count == Maze.Length - numberOfPits)
            {
                var msg = "Path " + pathCount++ + " : " + string.Join("->", pathTraversed.Reverse());
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
            }
            pathTraversed.Pop();
            return;
        }

        pathTraversed.Push(node.Name);
        node.IsVisited = true;

        Traverse(node.RightNode);   //
        Traverse(node.DownNode);    // Move to Next Node
        Traverse(node.LeftNode);    //  
        Traverse(node.UpNode);      //

        if (node.Name != pathTraversed.Peek())
            throw new Exception("Error in Logic.");

        node.IsVisited = false;
        pathTraversed.Pop();
    }
}
```

### and here is the program in Java

```
public class PathFinder
{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][] set1 = new int[][] { { 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1 }};
    ObservableStack<String> observableStack = new ObservableStack<String>();
    StackObserver stackObserver = new StackObserver(plotter);
    Maze maze = new Maze(set1,(IPathFinderStack<String>)observableStack);
    maze.findPaths();                   
  }
}

public class Maze {

private Node[][] nodes;

IPathFinderStack<String> pathTraversed;

private int numberOfPits = 0;

private  int result = 0;

public  Node[][] getVector(){
    return nodes;
}

public Maze(int[][] matrix ,IPathFinderStack<String> stack){
    pathTraversed = stack;
    addNodes(matrix);
}   

public void addNodes(int[][] matrix)    {

    int rows = matrix.length;
    int cols = matrix[0].length;

    nodes = new Node[rows][cols];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            Node node = nodes[i][j];

            if (node == null){
                node = new Node(matrix[i][j]);
                nodes[i][j] = node;
            }

            if (!(i - 1 < 0))
                nodes[i-1][j].setDownNode(node);

            if (!((i + 1) > rows - 1))
            {
                Node downNode = nodes[i+1][j];
                if (downNode == null)
                    nodes[i + 1][j] = new Node(matrix[i+1][j]);
                nodes[i + 1][j].setUpNode(node);
            }

            if (!(j - 1  < 0))
                nodes[i][j-1].setRightNode(node);

            if (!(j + 1 > cols - 1)){
                Node leftNode = nodes[i][j+1];
                if (leftNode == null)
                    nodes[i][j+1] = new Node(matrix[i][j+1]);
                nodes[i][j+1].setLeftNode(node);
            }

            String name =  new String(new char[] {(char) (65 + i), (char)(48 + j)});

            node.setName(name);

            if (node.isPit())
                this.numberOfPits ++;
        }
    }
}

public void findPaths(){    

    Node startNode = nodes[0][0];

    pathTraversed.push(startNode.getName());

    Traverse(startNode.getRightNode());
    Traverse(startNode.getDownNode());
    Traverse(startNode.getLeftNode());
    Traverse(startNode.getUpNode());
}   

private void Traverse(Node node){   

        if (node == null)
            return ;

    if (node.isEntrance() || node.isVisited() || node.isPit())
        return ;

    if (node.isExit()){

            pathTraversed.push(node.getName());
        if (pathTraversed.getLength() == (nodes[0].length * nodes.length) - numberOfPits){
            String msg = "Path found" + (++result);
            Logger.Log(msg);
            Logger.Log(pathTraversed.toString());
        }

        pathTraversed.pop();
        return;             
    }

    pathTraversed.push(node.getName());
    node.setVisited(true);

    Traverse(node.getRightNode());
    Traverse(node.getDownNode());
    Traverse(node.getLeftNode());
    Traverse(node.getUpNode());

    node.setVisited(false);
    pathTraversed.pop();        
}
}

public class Node
{
private String name;
private int val;
private boolean isPit;
private boolean isVisited;
private boolean isEntrance;
private boolean isExit;

private Node downNode;
private Node upNode;
private Node leftNode;
private Node rightNode;

public Node(int val){
    this.val = val;
    this.isPit = (val == 1);
    this.isEntrance = (val == 2);
    this.isExit = (val == 3);
    this.isVisited = false;         
}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

public void setName (String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isPit(){
    return isPit;
}

public boolean isVisited(){
    return isVisited;
}

public void setVisited(boolean isVisited)   {
    this.isVisited = isVisited;
}

public boolean isEntrance(){
    return isEntrance;
}

public boolean isExit(){
    return isExit;
}

public Node getDownNode(){
    return downNode;
}

public void setDownNode(Node node){
    downNode = node;
}

public Node getUpNode(){
    return upNode;
}

public  void setUpNode(Node node){
    upNode = node;
}

public Node getLeftNode(){
    return leftNode;
}

public void setLeftNode(Node node){
    leftNode = node;
}

public Node getRightNode(){
    return rightNode;
}   

public void setRightNode(Node node) {
    rightNode = node;
}
}
```

the ObservableStack is a normal stack made of array. i made it observable to connect it to applet to animate the traversal.

I hope i have provided enough detail.

Comment: Provide code? There might be something in how it's written between the two.

Comment: I suggest retesting with a smaller dataset.

Comment: what jvm are you using with what settings?

Comment: You may be filling up the heap and it's getting stuck

Comment: @luketorjussen I was thinking that too. I am curious to see the algorithm to see if it is a difference in memory management, compile time optimization, code differences, etc

Comment: Was the java version error free?

Comment: i didn't provide the code first because i thought that there will be some compiler switch to optimize recursion in java, and expected reply on it.

Comment: You're really asking, "Why is my java version slower than my c# version?" You haven't provided any evidence that recursion has anything to do with the difference. You are using collection classes from the API, which might have quite different implementations. I think the best thing you could do is either a) run the java version in a profiler and see where it's spending all it's time, or b) take some part you think is the culprit, and write a very small, simple test that does only that thing a million times in C# and Java, and see if that is really where the difference is.

Comment: Provide compiler settings or it didn't happen.

Comment: @hatchet : The only difference between my c# and java code is the use of ObservableStack in java instead of java.util.Stack. ObservableStack is a simple stack implementation. i don't think that will cause this much diff.

Answer (score 1):

I have coded differently and got a faster time.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PathFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] set1 = new int[][]{{2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1}};

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Maze maze = new Maze(set1);
        List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
        maze.findPaths(0, 0, new StringBuilder(), paths);
        System.out.printf("Paths found %,d%n", paths.size());
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Took %,.1f seconds%n", time / 1e9);
    }
}

class Node {
    final int num;
    private boolean traversed;
    private final String name;

    Node(int num, String name) {
        this.num = num;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isTraversed() {
        return traversed;
    }

    public void setTraversed(boolean traversed) {
        this.traversed = traversed;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isExit() {
        return num == 3;
    }

    public boolean isPit() {
        return num == 1;
    }
}

class Maze {
    private final Node[][] nodes;
    private final int rows, cols;
    private final int nonPits;

    public Maze(int[][] matrix) {
        rows = matrix.length;
        cols = matrix[0].length;

        nodes = new Node[rows][cols];
        int nonPits = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                nodes[i][j] = new Node(matrix[i][j], "" + (char) ('A' + i) + (char) ('0' + j));
                if (!nodes[i][j].isPit())
                    nonPits++;
            }
        this.nonPits = nonPits;
    }

    public void findPaths(int x, int y, StringBuilder path, List<String> paths) {
        if (x < 0 || x >= cols) return;
        if (y < 0 || y >= rows) return;
        Node node = nodes[y][x];
        if (node.isTraversed() || node.isPit()) return;

        node.setTraversed(true);
        int length = path.length();
        path.append(node.getName());
        if (node.isExit()) {
            if (path.length() == nonPits*2) {
                paths.add(path.toString());
                if (paths.size() % 10000 == 0)
                    System.out.printf("... found %,d paths%n", paths.size());
            }
        } else {
            findPaths(x - 1, y, path, paths);
            findPaths(x + 1, y, path, paths);
            findPaths(x, y - 1, path, paths);
            findPaths(x, y + 1, path, paths);
        }

        path.setLength(length);
        node.setTraversed(false);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Paths found 40,616
Took 81.1 seconds
```

---

A lot of the time is spent recording the paths. If it just counts the paths (which requires the same amount of recursion)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class PathFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] set1 = new int[][]{{2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1}};

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Maze maze = new Maze(set1);
        long[] count = {0L};
        maze.findPaths(0, 0, 1, count);
        System.out.printf("Paths found %,d%n", count[0]);
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Took %,.1f seconds%n", time / 1e9);
    }
}

class Node {
    final int num;
    private boolean traversed;
    private final String name;

    Node(int num, String name) {
        this.num = num;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isTraversed() {
        return traversed;
    }

    public void setTraversed(boolean traversed) {
        this.traversed = traversed;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isExit() {
        return num == 3;
    }

    public boolean isPit() {
        return num == 1;
    }
}

class Maze {
    private final Node[][] nodes;
    private final int rows, cols;
    private final int nonPits;

    public Maze(int[][] matrix) {
        rows = matrix.length;
        cols = matrix[0].length;

        nodes = new Node[rows][cols];
        int nonPits = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                nodes[i][j] = new Node(matrix[i][j], "" + (char) ('A' + i) + (char) ('0' + j));
                if (!nodes[i][j].isPit())
                    nonPits++;
            }
        this.nonPits = nonPits;
    }

    public void findPaths(int x, int y, int depth, long[] count) {
        if (x < 0 || x >= cols) return;
        if (y < 0 || y >= rows) return;
        Node node = nodes[y][x];
        if (node.isTraversed() || node.isPit()) return;

        node.setTraversed(true);
        if (node.isExit()) {
            if (depth == nonPits) {
                count[0]++;
                if (count[0] % 10000 == 0)
                    System.out.printf("... found %,d paths%n", count[0]);
            }
        } else {
            findPaths(x - 1, y, depth + 1, count);
            findPaths(x + 1, y, depth + 1, count);
            findPaths(x, y - 1, depth + 1, count);
            findPaths(x, y + 1, depth + 1, count);
        }
        node.setTraversed(false);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Paths found 40,616
Took 58.5 seconds
```

Comment: I missed that the paths must traverse every square except the pits.

Comment: Updated now to count only paths which traverse every square. Looking at you code again, the delay could be in your Logger.Log as this can be very slow on some systems depending on what it does.

Comment: awesome.. mine was taking 13 mins.

Comment: Logger has nothing except system.out.println()

Comment: Even println to a MS-DOS window can be amazingly slow. ;)

Comment: what compiler optimization you used ? because in my computer it is taking far more than 58.5 secs.

Comment: You can replace `path.append((char)('A' + x)).append((char)('0'+y));` with `path.append(node.getName());`